# Meta-refresh content doesn't return to proper page

Tags: html, meta-tags, meta

I'm a bit confused how this work and how to use it. I have a page which is loaded after button is clicked. When the user is deleted I want to back to users.php page. What I tried so far and didn't work is:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=admin/users.php">
```

also this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=users.php">
```

I get 404.php error. Files are in same directory. I also have in head this

```
<base href="http://example.com/app/admins/">
```

The path to users.php is `example.com/app/admins/admin/users.php`

Edit: ***flash session message***

`userdelete.php`

```
            if (isset($_POST)) {
               $_SESSION['postIsSet'] = 'Deleted!!';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['postIsSet'] = false;
            }
            header('Location: users.php');
```

In `users.php`

```
       if (isset($_SESSION['postIsSet'])) {
           if ($_SESSION['postIsSet'] == true) {
               echo $_SESSION['postIsSet'];
                    unset($_SESSION['postIsSet']);
           } else {
               echo "Post is not set - Flash Message";
           }
        }
        else {}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `header('Location: http://example.com/app/admins/');` instead?

Comment: I want to show some message before to redirect but I don't know how to show this message on users.php i.e. previous page. That's why I trying with refresh. For example I'm in users.php and click on `Delete` button. This load `userDelete.php`. How when I delete user and back to users.php to show message that is successfully deleted?

Comment: `header('Location: http://example.com/app/admins/');` is working great but the problem is the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you can use `header()` to redirect to other page.

```
header('Location: http://example.com');
```

But you can't output anything before headers. Since you want to output some message too, you can use this code:

```
    header("refresh: 2; http://www.example.com/");
    echo <<< MESSAGE
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Some message to show
    </body>
</html>
MESSAGE;
```

It will redirect user after 2 seconds also showing some code. If you need more complex code, you can use [`ob_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) functions to gather any output and later output it.

---

*Flash Message Example*

```
[doStuff.php]

session_start();

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['postIsSet'] = true; // or some string
} else {
    $_SESSION['postIsSet'] = false;
}

header('Location: http://example.com/user.php');

[user.php]

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['postIsSet'])) {
   if ($_SESSION['postIsSet'] == true) {
       // If you set message in session, you can do `echo $_SESSION['postIsSet'];`
       echo "Post is set - Flash Message"; 
   } else {
       echo "Post is not set - Flash Message";
   }
   unset($_SESSION['postIsSet']);
} else {
   // Flash message is not set yet.
}
```

Comment: but I want to output the message in previous page i.e. redirect me to page that I want and show this message there.

Comment: @Goro Add some key to session that indicates need for message, than when redirected, check if there is this key in session, if yes, than output message. Google it for `php flash message`

Comment: I have found some info about it but I can't implement it. I get errors but I guess I should post new question.

Comment: @Goro Check updated answer, example of flash message. Not tested.

Comment: it's working. Just one last question. Is there a way after I'm on the previous page and see the message when I refresh page to disappear. Now the message is still there even if I refresh that page?

Comment: @Goro yes, right after showing message, do `unset($_SESSION['postIsSet']);` to remove element from session array

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. It seems to work just perfectly now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Works fine for me](http://jsbin.com/hehozu/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="http://example.com/app/admins/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=admin/users.php">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="2; URL=http://example.com/app/admins/admin/users.php">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After I read your comments also if you still whant to use `header location` instead of refresh here is what you can do. This work fine to me:
In your `userDelete.php`

```
header('Location: users.php?msg=deleted');
```

In your users.php

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
   echo $_GET['msg'];
}
```

It's work just fine